# How to fix An "Expired Timestamp" error?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

I have installed and reinstalled Ubuntu One on my Windows7 64bit System and I always get a "Expired Time stamp" Error.
What can I do?

The Error also when clicking on the Links in the Sync-Panel (for example "Edit your service online). The Error than is display in the browser:

*Expired time stamp: given 1318613351 and now 1318526904 has a greater difference than threshold 900*

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at my system time and could not find anything wrong with it. I now just looked up the two timestemps and there are apart a whole day. I reset my system time to the correct day and now it works. Thanks